# Как отслеживать checked элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно сделать так чтобы в зависимости от того, какой `input` на данный момент активен, показывался определенный контент. Т.е. если выбран первый `input` то `.content1` (Он по умолчанию, даже когда ничего не выбрано), если второй, то `.content2`

```css
.content2 {
  display: none;
}

.content {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content content1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero perferendis totam molestiae earum beatae qui, assumenda error nulla neque pariatur autem eos quasi cum, culpa aperiam reiciendis delectus dolores fugit?</div>
<div class="content content2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, tenetur est, libero magnam vel minima alias harum autem sequi blanditiis commodi ad quo facilis, accusamus laudantium ipsum dolore laborum ab.</div>

<input type="radio" name='variable' id='id1'>
<label for="id1">Variable 1</label>
<input type="radio" name='variable' id='id2'>
<label for="id2">Variable 2</label>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function update() {
  var i;
  var blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".content");
  for (i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    blocks[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  
  var block = "content1";
  var radios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio'][name='variable']");
  for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked)
      block = radios[i].dataset.block;
  }

  document.querySelector(".content." + block).style.display = "block";
}

update();
```

```css
.content1 {
  color:blue;
}
.content2 {
  display: none;
  color:red;
}

.content {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content content1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero perferendis totam molestiae earum beatae qui, assumenda error nulla neque pariatur autem eos quasi cum, culpa aperiam reiciendis delectus dolores fugit?</div>
<div class="content content2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, tenetur est, libero magnam vel minima alias harum autem sequi blanditiis commodi ad quo facilis, accusamus laudantium ipsum dolore laborum ab.</div>

<input type="radio" name='variable' id='id1' data-block="content1" onchange="update()">
<label for="id1">Variable 1</label>
<input type="radio" name='variable' id='id2' data-block="content2" onchange="update()">
<label for="id2">Variable 2</label>
```

Comment: Как оно вообще работает? Тут же даже нет слушателя какого-нибудь события... И еще вопрос, что значит этот кусок кода? querySelector(".content." + block)  Какой селектор в итоге будет браться?

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi Но работает же! Слушатели событий - `onchange="update()"`. Селектор будет `".content.content1"` или `".content.content2"`.

Answer (score 3):

Если я Вас правильно понял, это можно сделать и без JS. То что Вы описали, обыкновенные табы.

```css
.tabs-widget{position:relative;text-align:center}
.tab-trigger{position:absolute;clip:rect(0, 0, 0, 0)}
label{margin:0 20px;cursor:pointer}
label:hover{background:gray}
.scroller{display:none;position:absolute;left:50%;transform:translatex(-50%);margin-top:10px;width:400px}
#tab-1-1:checked ~ #tab_1_1, #tab-1-2:checked ~ #tab_1_2,#tab-1-3:checked ~ #tab_1_3{display:block}
#tab-1-1:checked ~ label[for='tab-1-1'], #tab-1-2:checked ~ label[for='tab-1-2'],#tab-1-3:checked ~ label[for='tab-1-3']{background:#000;color:#fff}
.scroller:nth-of-type(1){color:red}
.scroller:nth-of-type(2){color:green}
.scroller:nth-of-type(3){color:blue}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-widget">
  <input class="tab-trigger" type="radio" id="tab-1-1" name="radio" checked="checked"/>
  <label for="tab-1-1">LINK1</label>
  <input class="tab-trigger" type="radio" id="tab-1-2" name="radio"/>
  <label for="tab-1-2">LINK2</label>
  <input class="tab-trigger" type="radio" id="tab-1-3" name="radio"/>
  <label for="tab-1-3">LINK3</label>
  <div class="scroller" id="tab_1_1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi recusandae error corrupti molestias tenetur obcaecati a? Saepe magnam animi iure harum quibusdam unde sit reprehenderit accusamus dolorum, quo quis quidem?</div>
  <div class="scroller" id="tab_1_2">Loremのイプサムのニンジンは、リベートを強化します。誤って受け入れた場合面倒バウンド盲目になりますか？心の中で、これらの偉大な悲しみの一部を非難する権利、多くの場合、男性は全く不明である何の事、彼がどこから来るかで障害を見つけますか？</div>
  <div class="scroller" id="tab_1_3">Lorem ipsum गाजर बढ़ाया छूट। अगर गलती से स्वीकार कर लिया परेशानी बाध्य अंधा हो गए हैं? मन की है, है ना इन महान दु: ख में से कुछ का आरोप लगा है, अक्सर जहां वह, से आता है क्या बातें एक आदमी पूरी तरह अनजान हैं के साथ गलती खोजने के?</div>
</div>
```